# CSV file upload into database using shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, csv

I'm uploading a csv file using the script

```
 export IFS=","
 cat  $_csv_files | read a b c d;
```

Now I need the values in the column **c** of csv file to be inserted into the column **manufacture_name**  of the table **manufacturemap** in my Database.How will I accomplish that?

when I tried the code below

```
mysql -u $_db_user -p$_db_password $_db << eof
    INSERT INTO \`manufacturemap\`
    ( \`manufacture_name\`) VALUES ($c)
eof
```

I get:

```
 ERROR 1136 (21S01) at line 1: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I've been stuck here for the past few hours,Please help me.

Input(csv file):

```
    a,b,c,d
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/07/08,2014/07/08,"Cash Withdrawal by Cheque-173320--TT1421957901"
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/07/08,2014/07/08,"Cheque Paid-173261--TT1421951241"
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/07/08,2014/07/08,"Cheque Paid-173298--TT1421951226"
1.01100156278101E+15,2014/06/08,2014/06/08,"Cash Withdrawal by Cheque-173319--TT1421858465"
```

Comment: Please take care with your question - the script you've show is syntactically incorrect (missing a `do`) and does nothing. It's not clear what the relationship is between the variables that are being read (and discarded) and the variables in the next code block. Also, your MySQL command is missing an `eof` from the bottom. It's important for us to know exactly what you've tried so we can tell the difference between a mistake in your original code and a mistake in copying it into your question.

Comment: @Tom I'm really new to shell script,I know nothing about this :( what more information am i supposed to provide?

Comment: At the moment your question doesn't make sense. For example, you say you're using a script to upload a csv, then you show a script that sets some variables but does nothing with them. Show us what your input looks like and explain as clearly as possible how you want to insert it into your database.

Comment: @tom I've updated the question.I need to insert the data under column **c** in manufacture_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```bash
#! /bin/sh

values ()
{
    cat "$@" | \
    while IFS=, read -r a b c d; do
        printf '%s\n' "$c"
    done | \
    paste -sd, -
}

printf 'INSERT INTO `manufacturemap` (`manufacture_name`) VALUES (%s)\n' "$(values $_csv_files)" | \
    mysql -u"$_db_user" -p"$_db_password" "$_db"
```